# How can I make this RewriteRule working?

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

```
RewriteRule ^articles\.php\?id=([0-9]+)$ article-a$1.html [R=301,L]
```

I would like to have all links like articles.php?id=1211 pointing to article-a{ID}.html, how can I achieve this? What's wrong with this rule?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't match against the query string in a rewrite rule, you need to match against the `%{QUERY_STRING}` var in a condition and use the `%` backreference:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=([0-9]+)$ 
RewriteRule ^articles\.php$ article-a%1.html [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score -1):

Usefollowing,

```
RewriteRule ^articles.php?id=([0-9]+)$ article-a$1.html
```

Comment: Absolutely not. You can't test for the query string in the pattern of a RewriteRule.